# Can't use implicit or explicit receiver when inside Box scope

Tags: kotlin, compose-multiplatform

I'm learning Jetbrains' "Compose Multiplatform" which is based on Jetpack Compose.

**Some info**

- Kotlin: 1.5.31
- Intellij: 2021.3.1

So when building the code below I get the error:

`fun Modifier.align(alignment: Alignment.Horizontal): Modifier' can't be called in this context by implicit receiver. Use the explicit one if necessary`

This error is showing up at this line:

`Icon(Icons.Filled.Close, "", Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally))`

I have tried adding the full package to `Modifier` like `androidx.compose.ui.Modifier.align()` but it still errors out about the receiver. This error goes away if it is not inside either a `Row`, `Column`, or `Box` layout. I haven't tried many others to see if they have problems too. This framework is still alpha I do believe so I just wanna make sure I'm not missing something before I post an issue on github cause I can't find anyone else referencing this issue.

**Reproduce:**

1. Create new project (Compose Multiplatform Application)
2. Replace App.kt (common -> src -> commonMain -> kotlin) with code below

```
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Box
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.material.*
import androidx.compose.material.icons.Icons
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.Close
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.Menu
import androidx.compose.runtime.*
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontWeight
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp

@Composable
fun App() {

    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            TopAppBar {
                IconButton(onClick = {}) {
                    Icon(Icons.Filled.Menu, contentDescription = "")
                }
            }
        },
        drawerContent = {
            Box(modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp), contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
                Text("Some Text", fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold)
                Icon(Icons.Filled.Close, "", Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally))
            }

            Divider()
        }
    ) { }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modifier.align is more like child view's `layout_gravity` in FrameLayout. It's depend on outer layer (in compose you have Box, Row, Column).

`Alignment.CenterHorizontally` cannot be used in BoxScope.

Look at `Modifier.align`, it has three definition:

- [androidx.compose.foundation.layout.BoxScope#align(alignment: Alignment)](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:compose/foundation/foundation-layout/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/Box.kt;l=219?q=fun%20Modifier.align)
- [androidx.compose.foundation.layout.ColumnScope#align(alignment: Alignment.Horizontal)](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:compose/foundation/foundation-layout/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/Column.kt;l=154?q=fun%20Modifier.align)
- [androidx.compose.foundation.layout.RowScope#align(alignment: Alignment.Vertical)](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:compose/foundation/foundation-layout/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/Row.kt;l=158?q=fun%20Modifier.align)

See parameter, [CenterHorizontally](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:compose/ui/ui/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/Alignment.kt;l=111?q=CenterVertically) is `androidx.compose.ui.Alignment.Horizontal`.In BoxScope you can only use `androidx.compose.ui.Alignment`:

- TopStart
- TopCenter
- TopEnd
- CenterStart
- Center
- CenterEnd
- BottomStart
- BottomCenter
- BottomEnd

Here is a Modifier playground. https://github.com/c5inco/Compose-Modifiers-Playground

[image]
[image]

Comment: Ah, I took a look at the fun call and didn't notice that in the call it defines the extension methods in there. But cause the interface declares all of them I only saw that the IDE said it was available when it actually wasn't. If that makes sense. Thanks for the help!